# Target header nav dropdown being covered up by divs using jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I cant seem to target correctly the menu button below using jQuery. Shouldnt this work? here is the html:

```
<section id="main-menu" class="navbar-fixed-top" style="z-index: 1000;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="an image" alt="LOGO"></a>
                </div>
                <!-- START Responsive Menu HTML -->
                <div class="rm-container rm-layout-contracted">
                    <a id="rm-menu-btn" class="rm-toggle rm-button rm-show rm-active" href="#" tabindex="0">
                        Menu
                    </a>
```

And here is the JS.

```
console.log('it works');
jQuery( "a#rm-menu-btn" ).live( "click", function() {
    alert( "Goodbye!" ); 
});
```

how do i target this anchored text within so many divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use on method instead, The live() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.7, and removed in version 1.9.

```js
jQuery( "a#rm-menu-btn" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( "Goodbye!" ); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="main-menu" class="navbar-fixed-top" style="z-index: 1000;">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
   <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="an image" alt="LOGO"></a>
    </div>
    <!-- START Responsive Menu HTML -->
    <div class="rm-container rm-layout-contracted">
     <a id="rm-menu-btn"
      class="rm-toggle rm-button rm-show rm-active"
      href="#" tabindex="0">Menu</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Check the snippet added with this post also I have created a pen for you you will find it [here](https://codepen.io/asifsaho/pen/ZRmoVN)